# How to restart for while loops after user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started coding and I'm slowly understanding it. For my class we have to make a children's program to practice their math and ask them if they would like to try again if it is correct. I cannot understand how to get my while True loop to restart if they input Y. Any tips? Here is my code:

```
    #Addition
        A = int(input("What is %i + %i =" %(N1, N2)))
        while add != N1 + N2:
                 add = int(input("Incorrect, what is %i + %i = " %(N1,N2)))
        while add == N1 + N2:
                 repeat =(input("Correct! would you like to try again? Y/N "))
        if repeat == 'n':
                break
        if repeat == 'y':
                continue
if op == "-":
    #Subrtraction
        s = int(input("What is %i - %i =" %(N1, N2)))
        while s != N1 - N2:
                 s = int(input("Incorrect, what is %i - %i = " %(N1,N2)))
        while s == N1 - N2:
                 repeat =(input("Correct! would you like to try again? Y/N "))
if op == "*":
     #Multiply
        m = int(input("What is %i - %i =" %(N1, N2)))
        while m != N1 * N2:
                 m = int(input("Incorrect, what is %i - %i = " %(N1,N2)))
        while m == N1 * N2:
                 repeat =(input("Correct! would you like to try again? Y/N "))
```

Answer (score 0):

This program structure does not make sense.

You can do:

```
while True:
    num1 = int(input("num1 "))
    num2 = int(input("num2 "))
    op = '+'
    calc = -1

    if op == "+":
        while calc != num1 + num2:
            calc = int( input(f"Whats {num1} {op} {num2}?"))
    elif op == "-":
        pass # code the others 
    elif op == "*":
        pass # code the others 
    elif op == "/":
        pass # code the others - use float where needed instead of int 
        # comparing floats is difficult due to float math rounding imperfection

    print("Correct!" , num1, op, num2,"=",calc)

    again = input("Again? Y  to do it again: ").lower()

    if again != "y": 
        break    # leaves the while True
```

Answer (score 0):

for doing it you can define a function. Maybe it's little more complicated than what you do in class, but still it's pretty basic, so you can learn it easly :)
when using a function, remember to call it in the first time so it'll work.
here's an example:

```
def function_name():
    while True:
        '''your code'''
        repeat =(input("Correct! would you like to try again? Y/N "))
        if repeat == "y":
            function_name() # wach time the user say "y" the code calls the function again.
        break # the break will finish the while loop and will close the program.

function_name() # that's where I call the function the first time.
```

by the way, you don't actually have to use the while loop if you are using the function. but I assume it was your work in class so I'll leave it that way :)

Comment: I think `recursion` is a larger leap for folks, who are beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to enter a `while` loop first and then take input from the user or determining whether the answer is correct or not and other questions...

```py
# coding: utf-8

# Start of the 1st Question
redo="y"
A1=-1 # can be any integer but not the correct answer
n1, n2 = 2, 3

while (A1 != n1 + n2) or redo.lower()=="y":
    # ask the question
    A1 = int(input("What is the sum of %i and %i : " % (n1, n2)))

    # if answer is correct
    if A1 == n1 + n2:
        redo = input("Correct ! Would you like to try again? (Y/[N]) : ")
        if redo.lower() == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        print("Your Answer : %d is Incorrect!" % A1)
```